# Woocommerce cart custom field error on update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to add a custom field on each product on cart. I got the code from 
[WooCommerce: Add input field to every item in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650019/woocommerce-add-input-field-to-every-item-in-cart/21818028#21818028)

but the update is not working. I tried to change the global $woocommerce to WC() but still it gives me 500 (Internal Server Error) on chrome console everytime I click update. heres the code:

cart.php:

```
<td class="product-url">
<?php
    $html = sprintf( '<div class="url"><input type="text" name="cart[%s][url]" value="%s" size="4" title="Url" class="input-text url text" /></div>', $cart_item_key, esc_attr( $values['url'] ) );
    echo $html;
?>
```

function.php (This is not a snippet so do not run):

```html
// get from session your URL variable and add it to item
add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'cart_item_from_session', 99, 3);
function cart_item_from_session( $data, $values, $key ) {
    $data['url'] = isset( $values['url'] ) ? $values['url'] : '';
    return $data;
}
 
// this one does the same as woocommerce_update_cart_action() in plugins\woocommerce\woocommerce-functions.php
// but with your URL variable
// this might not be the best way but it works
add_action( 'init', 'update_cart_action', 9);
function update_cart_action() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( ( ! empty( $_POST['update_cart'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['proceed'] ) ) && $woocommerce->verify_nonce('cart')) {
        $cart_totals = isset( $_POST['cart'] ) ? $_POST['cart'] : '';
        if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                if ( isset( $cart_totals[ $cart_item_key ]['url'] ) ) {
                    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['url'] = $cart_totals[ $cart_item_key ]['url'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
// this is in Order summary. It show Url variable under product name. Same place where Variations are shown.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'item_data', 10, 2 );
function item_data( $data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['url'] ) ) {
        $data['url'] = array('name' => 'Url', 'value' => $cart_item['url']);
    }
    return $data;
}
 
// this adds Url as meta in Order for item
add_action ('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_item_meta', 10, 2);
function add_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {
    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Url', $values['url'] );
}
```

Comment: You should better add your hidden imput custom field in the product themselves, instead in the cart. Kindly but your code is quiet fuzzy. I think that this could be simpler and efficient in a different way. This is a different thread but this is a way even if is not the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423161/save-product-custom-field-radio-button-value-in-cart-and-display-it-on-cart-page/43427686#43427686